# How to select this button using Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I am trying to use Python and Selenium to click either Yes or No on these buttons:

[image]

The HTML for these buttons is as follows:

[image]

I've tried to select based on the XPath:

```
isbnButton = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-toggle='haveisbn'")
```

as suggested by a friend, but it's giving me an error that says the string is not a valid XPath expression. I know pretty much nothing about XPath and am doing a tutorial right now while I await answers, but I'm hoping someone can guide me in the right direction.

What I originally tried was:

```
dontHaveISBN = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('btn radio btn-radio btn-primary not-active w-100')
dontHaveISBN[1].click()
```

but that wasn't recognizing any elements.

How would you select and click on these buttons?

Comment: Post your URL. It's better to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can give it a try with xpath again (try to copy exactly the xpath from the source code):

```
dontHaveISBN=driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath_here')
dontHaveISBN.click()
```

Comment: How do I copy the xpath from the source code?  I literally know next to nothing about xpaths.

Comment: I just downloaded Firebug and figured it out.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!  I didn't realize it was even possible to copy the exact xpath until you said that.

Comment: @Oxymoronica : It's not a good practice to use xpath which is generated by FireBug/ firePath . As a beginner you might prefer that , But you should know how to write our own css selector or xpath.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
yes_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Yes')))
yes_button.click()
```

It's better to use **Link Text** than **XPATH**.

In case you want to use only xpath then that would be :

```
//a[text()='Yes']
```

Note that you will have to import these :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

If you want to learn more about xpath then you can refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

In the `xpath` try you forgot the closing `]`, that's why it isn't valid. But there is a bigger issue with this locator: it matches the `NO` button as well.

In the `class_name` try you gave multiple classes as parameter, `find_elements_by_class_name` receives only one class as parameter.

`data-id` attribute seems to be unique, you can use it

```
# Yes button
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-id="1"]')

# No button
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-id="0"]')

# using xpath
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-id="1"]')
```

Or using the text

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Yes')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="Yes"]')
```